# If a bounded function is integrable on each interval $[a,1]$, then it is integrable on $[0,1]$.

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-sum

Let  $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$  bounded,such that  $\forall a $  with  $0<a<1$, $f$ is integrable at the interval $ [a,1]$,show that f is integrable at  $[0,1]$.

As $f$ is bounded, $\exists M>0$ such that  $|f(x)| \leq M, \forall x \in [0,1]$.

Let $0<\epsilon<1$ .As $f$ is integrable at $[\epsilon,1]$, $\exists $ partition $P_1$ of $[\epsilon,1]$ ,such that:

$$U(f,P_1)-L(f,P_1)< \epsilon$$

Now,we consider the partition $P_2=\{0\} \cup P_1$ of $[0,1]$.

It is :

$$U(f,P_2)-L(f,P_2)=(\epsilon-0) \cdot \sup f([0, \epsilon])+U(f,P_1)-(\epsilon-0) \cdot \inf f([0, \epsilon])-L(f,P_1)$$

I jut wanted to know if $\sup f([0, \epsilon])=M \text{ and } \inf f([0, \epsilon])=-M$ or if it is just $\sup f([0, \epsilon]) \leq M \text{ and } \inf f([0, \epsilon]) \leq -M$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Just $\sup f([0, \epsilon]) \leq M \text{ and } \inf f([0, \epsilon]) \leq -M$" (obviously).

Comment: @Did I misunderstood. In my analysis class, a partition was always a family of intervals, not a set of division points. I see OP has it differently here, so I removed my comment.

Comment: Edit to my previous comment: $\inf f([0, \epsilon]) \geq -M$.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I will remember it,for my next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $\delta<\text{mini}\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{4M}\}$. And then choose a partition for the $\delta$. Then we will get $U(P_2,f)-L(P_2,f)\leq 2\delta M<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ where $P_2=\{0\}$ and $P_1=\{\delta,\ldots,1\}$.

Comment: Is it an other way to show what the exercise demands?

Comment: No no. Just I filled the gap of the above argument  with rigorous estimate.