# Prove that if $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ and integrable in each interval $[c,b]$ with $a<c<b,$ then $\int_a^b f =\lim_{c\to a+}\int_c^b f$

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that if $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ and integrable in each interval $[c,b]$ with $a<c<b,$ then $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ and also
$$\int_a^b f =\lim_{c\to a+}\int_c^b f$$

I already proved the integrability of $f$:

Given $\varepsilon>0$ we should find a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon$

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\sum_{k=1}^n(M_k-m_k)\Delta x_k=(M_1-m_1)(x_1-a)+\sum_{k=2}^n(M_k-m_k)\Delta x_k$$
I have to find $x_1$ small enough such that $(M_1-m_1)(x_1-a)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

$f$ is bounded,  $\implies \exists M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M \ \forall x \in [a,b].$ And $M_1-m_1\leq2M$. With the hypothesis, $f$ is integrable in $[x_1,b] \implies \exists P_1$ partition of $[x_1,b]$ with $U(f,P_1)-L(f,P_1)<\frac\varepsilon2$.

If we have a partition $P=\{a\}\cup P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)\leq 2M(x_1-a)+U(f,P1)-L(f,P_1)<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon$, so, $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$

How can I find that $$\int_a^b f =\lim_{c\to a+}\int_c^b f$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a bounded function is integrable on each interval $[a,1]$, then it is integrable on $[0,1]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845738/if-a-bounded-function-is-integrable-on-each-interval-a-1-then-it-is-integra)

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net That answers the part Juju9704 has been able to answer themselves, and just want confirmation on. It does not answer the final part of their problem, where they have made no headway.

Comment: Once you know that the function is integrabe in $[a,b]$ you could write $$\left|\int_a^b f dx - \int_c^b fdx\right|$$ as $$\left|\int_a^b f dx -U(f,P)+U(f,P)-U(f,P_1)+U(f,P_1)- \int_c^b fdx\right|,$$ then use triangular inequality and upper bound the three terms you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ we have $$\int_a^b f \, dx = \int_a^c f \, dx + \int_c^b f \, dx$$ but $$0 \le \lim_{c \to a+} \left|\int_a^c f \, dx\right| \le \lim_{c \to a+}\int_a^c |f| \, dx \le \lim_{c \to a+}M(c-a) = 0$$ hence $$\lim_{c \to a+}\int_a^c f \, dx = 0$$ and so in total we get:

$$\int_a^b f \, dx = \lim_{c \to a+} \int_a^b f \, dx = \lim_{c \to a+}\int_a^c f \, dx + \lim_{c \to a+}\int_c^b f \, dx = \lim_{c \to a+}\int_c^b f \, dx$$